# Unable to get the cycle 2 plugin

Tags: 7, views

I have installed Views Slideshow module 7.x.3.1.  Also, inside the sites/all/libraries I downloaded the [cycle2 plugin](http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js). 
I placed jquery.cycle2.min.js into the jquery.cycle2 folder, so it is at sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle2/jquery.cycle2.min.js.

When I tried creating a view using *Format : slideshow*, I encountered the following error:

> CYCLE OPTIONS You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a
>   directory in sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle, and then copy
>   jquery.cycle.all.min.js or jquery.cycle.all.js into it. You can find
>   the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle.

[image]

Even after installing the cycle plugin in the libraries folder, I could not see an option for cycle2.

Along with with views slideshow, I need  [pager effect](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/pager.php) and [continuous effect](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/continuous.php), with vertical effect instead of horizontal effect.

Answer (score 1):

Readme says

1) Assure that you are using Views 3.x. http://drupal.org/project/views

2) Upload/install the Libraries API module. http://drupal.org/project/libraries

3) Upload/install the ctools library. http://drupal.org/project/ctools

4) Create a sites/all/libraries directory on your server.

5) Create a directory within sites/all/libraries named jquery.cycle.

6) Locate/download the jQuery cycle plugin. http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle

7) Upload/install the jQuery cycle plugin: place it inside the jquery.cycle
   directory.
8) Enable the Views slideshow and Views Slideshow: Cycle modules

9) You should now see the new views style option called "Slideshow"

**You need to install cycle plugin not cycle 2**. Try installing using cycle plugin and follow above instructions.

There is a sandbox module available if you want to use Cycle 2 plugin.

You can download using git commands.

git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/BenYoung/1832338.git views_slideshow__cycle2

cd views_slideshow__cycle2

Follow the installations instruction in project page for the same.

Comment: I want to get the pager functionality present in cycle2 and not present in cycle as mentioned in the post.So i want to add the cycle2 plugin.I have gone through the steps as you have mentioned and even installed cycle plugin

Comment: But how can I add feature of pager and continuous effect using views slideshow cycle plugin ? Is there any way to achieve it?Pls check the link for pager effect in the post using cylce2

Comment: Check these links https://drupal.org/sandbox/BenYoung/1832338 and https://drupal.org/node/1801332

Comment: I have tried adding files jquery.cycle2.swipe.js  and   jquery.cycle2.js but still it did not work?Is there any way out for pager configuration using cycle plugin or any other?

Comment: Did you check https://drupal.org/sandbox/BenYoung/1832338 module which says it supports Cycle 2 plugin ?

Comment: I worked as per the installation steps given

Comment: Can u elaborate how to get this sandbox project downloaded directly like the way we do it while downloading drupal modules

Comment: Updated answer with instructions...

Comment: http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/BenYoung/1832338.git I tried opening this url for downloading the git repository but it gives error 'not found on this server'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12569/discussion-between-harshal-and-anil-sagar)

Comment: the pager functionality is still not present in that module.

Comment: @harshal I have been using the original Cycle on Views Slideshow for while, and having the same issue when adding the Cycle2 Today. By adding the cycle2 file inside the "/libraries/jquery.cycle" directory would NOT make it work. I even run the cron and clear all caches with no luck. Hopefully someone know how.